# Overriding bootstrap with a custom.css.scss?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a Ruby on Rails application and I am doing a bit of styling for my project.

I am using the Bootstrap gem v3.0.0, but I dont know where to add my custom CSS file in my Rails project and where to call it.

I have a landing page:

```
<div class="container-full">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center v-center">
         <h1>Hello Landing</h1>

        <p class="lead">A sign-up page example for Bootstrap 3</p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="input-group" style="width:340px;text-align:center;margin:0 auto;">
            <input class="form-control input-lg" title="Don't worry. We hate spam, and will not share your email with anyone."
            placeholder="Enter your email address" type="text"> <span class="input-group-btn btn-default"><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button">OK</button></span>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /row -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center v-center" style="font-size:39pt;"> <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-google-plus"></i></a>  <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-facebook"></i></a> 
        <a
        href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-twitter"></i>
            </a> <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-github"></i></a>  <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pinterest"></i></a>

    </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

I have a custom CSS page:

```
html,body {
  height:100%;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Arial,sans-serif
  font-size:80px;
  color:#DDCCEE;
}

.lead {
    color:#DDCCEE;
}


/* Custom container */
.container-full {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  min-height:100%;
  background-color:#110022;
  color:#eee;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.container-full a {
  color:#efefef;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.v-center {
  margin-top:7%;
}
```

My application.css looks like this:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
group :assets do
  gem 'bootstrap-rails'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`bootstrap-rails` has been deprecated, use `bootstrap-sass` instead.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2' # sass-rails needs to be higher than 3.2
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'
```

Once you install the gem, make sure to restart your app/webserver.

Then rename your `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` file to `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss` and add the following:

```
@import "bootstrap";

html,body {
  height:100%;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Arial,sans-serif
  font-size:80px;
  color:#DDCCEE;
}

.lead {
  color:#DDCCEE;
}


/* Custom container */
.container-full {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  min-height:100%;
  background-color:#110022;
  color:#eee;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.container-full a {
  color:#efefef;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.v-center {
  margin-top:7%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for the template file where the bootstrap CSS is included, and add you own CSS link under that. If it is still not working, try adding `!important` to your styles.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your custom CSS file under `app/assets/stylesheets`, and you should declare your bootstrap files in your `application.css`, and thus adding the following after `*= require_tree .`

```
*= require bootstrap
*= require bootstrap_responsive
```

Your custom CSS should prevail and there shouldn't be any collision.